# Extract Strings from Java Classes

Tags: java, string, extract

I want to extract all Strings (texts, written in " ") in hundreds of java classes, to get them to a translator for a multilanguage platform translation.

Does somebody have an idea how I could do this? Any special free program or method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse has an "Externalize Strings" feature that creates a properties file of all of the strings within a class or classes. Other IDEs may have a similar feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, the wizard appears to work per single file, only, even when an Eclipse source folder is selected that contains multiple candidate files.

Comment: OTOH, this approach allows you to specify non-localizable strings, and to provide the translator some context, via the key name.

Answer (score 4):

If you use eclipse as your IDE, this is as simple as selecting your project and from the context menu select Source / Externalise Strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a program to use regular expressions to capture any groups encased in strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code, use Eclipse's externalize strings feature that Dave mentioned.

If you only have the class files, use the GNU strings tool, which finds any string sequences inside a binary file.

http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/strings.html

Comment: The `strings` command will also pick up a lot of extras like class names and variables.

Comment: Use the source luke... use the source... ( oops wrong thread )